# Help with 2 sets of prices for single product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price

I am opening my eshop and need a little help with product pricing what I dont understand is:

I have products and they come in different standards and 6 different prices.

For example: Product lamp comes in standards DN5, DN6, DN7, DN8 and every standard has 2 prices, DN5 for example has 2 prices 100.00 and 200.00 and so on...

Notice: these prices mentioned are not to be added up for example base price + 100.00 when user selects an option, prices 100.00 and 200.00 in this case are complete prices.

My problem is what to use attributes or custom options and how to set them up.

Here is one page which has exactly what I need (not made by magento unfortunately), 
it is good example (in tables on page are prices and variations of products and bellow is simple select product and thats it) : [example link](http://www.grejanje-expont.rs/prirubnice-sa-grlom.html)

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not support this out of the box (unfortunately).
But there is [an extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html) that claims to let you do that.
I haven't used it, but I see it recommended all over the web.
Give it a try.